# python pytorch-lighting element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I want to replicate someone else’s paper,this article uses the PyTorch-Lightning CLI interface.But i find that there are no gradients in the output during model training when using PyTorch-Lightning==1.6.3.Below is the experimental model code, I found that during model training, the variables labels and logits do not have gradients.Any suggestions in how to resolve the error or improve the code would be helpful.

```
from typing import Optional

import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from pytorch_lightning.core.lightning import LightningModule
from pytorch_lightning.utilities.types import STEP_OUTPUT
from torchmetrics import F1Score, MetricCollection, Precision, Recall


class Matcher(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        metrics_kwargs = { "task" :"binary","ignore_index": 0}
        metrics = MetricCollection(
            {
                "f1": F1Score(**metrics_kwargs),
                "prc": Precision(**metrics_kwargs),
                "rec": Recall(**metrics_kwargs),
            }
        )
        self.train_metrics = metrics.clone(prefix="train/")
        self.val_metrics = metrics.clone(prefix="val/")
        self.test_metrics = metrics.clone(prefix="test/")

    def common_step(self, batch, step: str) -> Optional[STEP_OUTPUT]:
        labels = batch.pop("labels", None)
        logits = self.forward(batch)

        # labels = torch.tensor(labels.float(), requires_grad=True)
        # logits = torch.tensor(logits, requires_grad=True)
        if labels is not None:
            # def fun(x1,x2):
            #     return torch.sub(x1, x2)
            #
            # loss=fun(labels,logits[:,1])
            # # loss=None
            # x1 = torch.tensor([3.0], requires_grad=True)
            # x2 = torch.tensor([3.0], requires_grad=True)
            # # 对函数进行计算
            # y = fun(x1, x2)
            # # 因为y是x的函数，所以y有梯度
            # print(y.grad_fn)
            loss = F.cross_entropy(logits, labels) if labels is not None else None

            metrics = getattr(self, f"{step}_metrics")
            probs = F.softmax(logits, dim=-1)

            #自行添加
            probs = probs[:, 1]
            probs = [1 if p>0.5 else 0 for p in probs]
            probs = torch.Tensor(probs)
            device = labels.device
            probs = probs.to(device)


            metrics(probs, labels)

            self.log_dict(metrics, prog_bar=True)
            self.log(f"{step}/loss", loss, prog_bar=True)
        else:
            loss = None

        return loss

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx: int) -> STEP_OUTPUT:
        return self.common_step(batch, "train")

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx: int) -> Optional[STEP_OUTPUT]:
        return self.common_step(batch, "val")

    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx: int) -> Optional[STEP_OUTPUT]:
        return self.common_step(batch, "test")

    def configure_callbacks(self):
        callbacks_kargs = {"monitor": "val/f1", "mode": "max"}

        early_stopping = EarlyStopping(patience=5, **callbacks_kargs)
        model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(**callbacks_kargs)
        return [early_stopping, model_checkpoint]
```